# Show notification badge in flutter firebase messaging

Tags: flutter, notifications

Greetings i am using firebase messaging to send notification to flutter app it works fine but the notification is received as the app icon in status bar and doesent pop the notification bar like any regular app . here is the code :

```
 _firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> notification) async {
    setState(() {
      notifications.add(
        Notifications(

          title: notification["notification"]["title"],
          body: notification["notification"]["body"],
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      );
    });
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> notification) async {
    setState(() {

      notifications.add(
        Notifications(
          title: notification["notification"]["title"],
          body: notification["notification"]["body"],
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      );
    });
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> notification) async {
    setState(() {
      notifications.add(
        Notifications(
          title: notification["notification"]["title"],
          body: notification["notification"]["body"],
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      );
    });
  },
);
```

is it manual setup to do so or what ?

Comment: please try to add a screenshot of what you are looking for